# How to emulate a form submit with Fetch?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

I need to emulate a form submit with the Fetch API but I don't have it working properly yet

This is my code:

```
const headers = new Headers({
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'accept-language': 'en-US',
 'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
});

 fetch(`/actions`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: new URLSearchParams(anObject).toString(),
});
```

This is the form  I'm trying to emulate

```
<form action="/actions" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="_self">
```

I still don't know how to add the target attribute to the Fetch. I don't know what other things I'm missing here.

Also if you know any other alternative for emulating a form submit with other tools, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The point of AJAX is to not reload the page, so the target attribute has no equivalent. `fetch()` doesn't display the result itself, you do that in the callback function.

Comment: Well, just do `window.location.reload()` ?